# Open in Low Resolution checkbox on Retina MacBook Pro checked and disabled

Tags: applications, macbook-pro, java

On a Retina MacBook Pro some Java applications (such as IDEA 11.1.3 that is supposed to support it) won't run in HiDPI mode. When I got to "Get Info" on the app, I can see that the "Open in Low Resolution" checkbox is checked and disabled. Is there a way to change this? I have Java 1.6.0_37 installed.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't sound like the application actually supports HiDPI mode.  Here's a tutorial for modifying Microsoft Word's application package so it will support HiDPI Mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRu1J.jpg.  Perhaps it would work for this application as well.

### Summary of the link:

- Make a backup copy of the application
- Open the application folder, then right click the app and choose "Show Package Contents"
- Edit Contents/info.plist
- Toward the bottom of the file, just before `</dict>`, add the following lines:

  ```
  <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
  <string>True</string>
  ```
- Move the app package out of the applications folder.  Then move it back in.
- The application may now allow a hacked, possibly glitchy retina mode.

Comment: This did not work for me on Retina iMac.

Comment: Works with VirusTotalUploader.app!