# How do I properly force osx to reload the Info.plist file of an application?

Tags: macos

On Yosemite 10.10, I was trying to use `defaults` to modify the `Info.plist` file of an app, but after such command, osx does not reload modified `Info.plist`.

I've tried to move the app around and reboot, as mentioned somewhere else as a way to force osx to reload `Info.plist`, but failed.

So here's the problem, **How do I force osx to reload the `Info.plist` file of an app?**

---

Specifically here is what I want to achieve:

Currently the flash in Firefox runs in low resolution when in fullscreen mode, to fix this I need to make the `Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container.app` HiDPI compatible.

[According to this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69038/open-in-low-resolution-checkbox-on-retina-macbook-pro-checked-and-disabled), after this command:

`defaults write /Application/Firefox/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container.app/Contents/Info.plist  NSHighResolutionCapable true`

I should be able to uncheck the "Open in Low Resolution" checkbox. But no, modifed `plugin-container.app` still has a greyed-out checkbox in its info panel. Rebooting does not solve the problem.

Here's the weird part: I moved the modified `plugin-container.app` to somewhere else, then I was able to uncheck that checkbox. But I moved it back and that checkbox became greyed-out again.

An work-around I found is

- copy another app to `/Application/Firefox/Contents/MacOS/` and renamed it to `plugin-container.app` (I call this the "fake `plugin-container.app`"),
- then replace fake one with the modified one.

In this way I can have the "Open in Low Resolution" checkbox back and am able to uncheck it, **but system doesn't update the app icon after replacing**, so now the app icon of the modified `plugin-container.app` is still the one of the fake `plugin-container.app`. 
A problem is fixed but another is created.

So what is the proper way to have the system reload the `Info.plist`?

Comment: You need to clear the cache folder.

Comment: Maybe LaunchServices should be rebuilt? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125402/icons-remains-the-same-after-i-have-changed-the-default-program-for-opening-the/126526#126526

Comment: @Buscar웃 I can locate the cache folder at `~/Library/Caches/` but not sure which folder is responsible for plist file caching.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek That fixed the icon glitch, thanks. But the main problem is not affected by a rebuild.

Comment: What made you believe that by modifying the Info.plist will change to HiDPI mode?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I've been doing this to many apps since Mavericks and, as I mentioned in my question, according to this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69038/open-in-low-resolution-checkbox-on-retina-macbook-pro-checked-and-disabled

Comment: This whole Info.plist thing is really annoying because starting an app is not observable in the least.

Answer (score 6):

I've just had this issue as we had to change `Info.plist` in our app and it failed to run for anyone who updated from the previous version of the app. The easiest way I found of clearing the `Info.plist` cache was simply to move the file to a different directory, then move it back. I'm still hoping to find a way of doing it pro grammatically, but this should do for your case.